# Is there a fast way to get the diagonal of the inverse of a banded Hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

Since inverting a matrix is often a bad idea, I am wondering if there is a better way to get just the diagonal of the inverse without inverting the whole thing. Note I need the whole diagonal, not the trace. For my application I need to compute the sums of pairs of terms on the diagonal (I'm not sure if there's a name for this, clearly not the same thing as the partial trace).

Edit:

If it makes a difference, the matrix is Hermitian. It has nonzero elements in the first three bands off the main diagonal, and ranges from 8×8 to 40×40. I'm also working with other matrices that have a similar form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 2\,c_{xy} & e^{-ix/4} & e^{-iy/4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[4pt]
 2\,c_{xy} & 2 & e^{iy/4} & e^{ix/4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[4pt]
 e^{ix/4} & e^{-iy/4} & 2 &  2\,c_{xy} & e^{-ix/4} & e^{iy/4} & 0 & 0 \\[4pt]
 e^{iy/4} & e^{-ix/4} & 2\,c_{xy} & 2 & e^{-iy/4} & e^{ix/4} & 0 & 0\\[4pt]
 0 & 0 & e^{ix/4} & e^{iy/4} & 2 & 2\,c_{xy} & e^{-ix/4} & e^{-iy/4} \\[4pt]
 0 & 0 & e^{-iy/4} & e^{-ix/4} & 2\,c_{xy} & 2 & e^{iy/4} & e^{ix/4} \\[4pt]
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{ix/4} & e^{-iy/4} & 2 & 2\,c_{xy} \\[4pt]
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{iy/4} & e^{-ix/4} & 2\,c_{xy} & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $c_{xy} = \cos\left(\frac{x+y}{4}\right)$.

Comment: Calculate diagonal of the adjoint matrix and determinant of $A$ and you're good to go $A^{-1}=Det(A^{-1})\cdot adj(A)$

Comment: @Vsevolod, which changes the question to "what's a fast way to get the diagonal of the adjoint?".

Comment: Does your matrix have anything special about it (sparse, symmetric, etc.)?

Comment: While finding the adjoint of a matrix is not built-in, it seems to be defined in the Applications section of `Minors`. Not sure if it is the way to go though.

Comment: @J.M. there's only one way to calculate any element of adjoint though.

Comment: @Kiro, that was what I was alluding to, unless Vsevolod knows of a quicker route to obtaining the diagonal entries of the adjoint. Not the best complexity compared to just inverting to begin with, last I checked.

Comment: @Kiro 1 element of adjoint = 1 determinant.

Comment: The complexity of Cramer's rule for all diagonal elements of the inverse of a general, dense $n \times n$ matrix `A` is `n (n-1)^(n-1) + n^n` while LU-decomposition has complexity `n^3`. The latter can be obtained with `Diagonal[LinearSolve[A, IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray]]]`.

Comment: But quite surprisingly, `Diagonal[Inverse[A]]` is faster... (`n = 1000`)

Comment: If it makes a difference, the matrix is Hermitian. It has nonzero elements in the first two bands off the main diagonal, and ranges from 8x8 to 40x40

Comment: "first two bands off the main diagonal" - so, it's pentadiagonal, since you mention it's Hermitian?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it would actually be heptadiagonal, the first 3 bands above and below the diagonal

Comment: @J.M. thanks for fixing that for me

Comment: You might be interested in implementing the ideas in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2012.07.018).

Answer (score 1):

Proceed a similar way like @Vsevolod A. proposed.

Calculate the determinant of the submatrix of diagonal elements of the original matrix and divide by the total determinant.

```
subm[A_, diapos_] := Drop[A, {diapos}, {diapos}]

dialist[A_] := Table[Det[subm[A, pos]], {pos, 1, First@Dimensions[A]}]/Det[A]
```

Here the proof.

```
dialist[Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}]] == 
   Diagonal[Inverse[Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}]]]

(*   True   *)

dialist[Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {8, 8}]] == 
   Diagonal[Inverse[Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {8, 8}]]]

(*   True   *)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this appears to be quite a bit slower for my purpose compared to simply inverting the matrix. I have added some detail to the question, I don't know if it will help to find a faster solution.